# How can i reduce Seconds till windows starts have duration of 30 seconds

Tags: windows, boot, windows-error-reporting

How can i reduce windows usually takes while recovering from errors on startup :

[image]

why does the highlighted choice will be selected automatically was about 30 seconds?in modern processors the processing speed was high ,is it there any way to modify it back to  10 or 5 seconds?

With respective to user friendliness the time might be provided,how can i optimize/reduce the time?

Comment: You can change that time: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2285-operating-system-start-change-display-list-time.html

Comment: If the question was changed to "how do I adjust this ammount" instead of why does microsoft do what they do, which always gets treated poorly here at SU, the question would have better value, real fact answers, and survivability.   I hate the long waits, so hit the button.  There are times when an unattended computer is showing like that, and the 30 seconds does get it seen, where it would otherwise be screwing up on its own, that could be useful.  For the checkdsk time it can be critical in raid setups, where a checkdsk going off on a broken raid0 or odd file system could destroy data.

Comment: What you're asking isn't really clear.  However, that time is not advice on how long the computer requires, it is a delay to allow you to make a choice.

Comment: @Psycogeek  modified the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the amount of time a list of operating systems displays for on recovery, follow these steps:

- Boot to Windows
- Open Start
- Open Control Panel
- Switch to one of the Icon views (Large Icons or Small Icons)
- Select "System"
- In the System window - Select "Advanced System Settings"
- In the "Advanced System Properties" popup - Select the "Advanced" tab.
- Under "Startup and Recovery" (bottom group box) select "Settings"
- In the startup and recovery panel, set your otpions and then click "OK" back through the option boxes.

**Options:**

*Time to Display the List of Operating Systems at Boot* will give you a list of available operating system choices during normal bootup

*Time to Display the List of Operating Systems at Boot* will give you a list of available operating system options when your machine is recovery booting (normally, when an incorrect or unexpected shutdown was detected)

For your specific case, change the numbers from 30 to 5 or 10 and you're good to go.

Hope this helps.